# Swift - Referring to a class's type within the class

Tags: swift

When using static, type properties and methods from within the instance methods of the type, I'm often repeating the name of the type.

e.g.

```
class Foo
{
    // Type properties, methods

    static let kBrandColor = UIColor.red
    static let kMeaning = 42

    static func makeThing() -> Thing { ... }

    // Instance method

    func printStuff()
    {
        print("Brand Color is: \(Foo.kBrandColor)")
        print("The meaning of life is: \(Foo.kMeaning)")

        let thing = Foo.makeThing()
        print("Thing is \(thing)"
    }

    ...
}
```

These repeated references to "Foo" can (and often do) lead to bugs when copy-pasting, refactoring. It's very easy to forget to change a "Foo", and the code will still compile.

So, I've been using a pattern like this:

```
class Foo
{
    fileprivate typealias _ThisClass = Foo

    // Type properties, methods

    static let kBrandColor = UIColor.red
    static let kMeaning = 42

    static func makeThing() -> Thing { ... }

    // Instance method

    func printStuff()
    {
        print("Brand Color is: \(_ThisClass.kBrandColor)")
        print("The meaning of life is: \(_ThisClass.kMeaning)")

        let thing = _ThisClass.makeThing()
        print("Thing is \(thing)"
    }

    ...
}
```

This approach has the advantage of some copy-and-paste safety, but at the expense of a bit of boilerplate.

Is there a better, cleaner solution to this issue? (I've attempted to search SO, but getting the search terms right for this kind of problem has been tricky.)

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md

Comment: [edited] @Alexander. That is awesome. I'm very glad the proposal was accepted. OTOH, the proposal was accepted over two years ago... Thanks. – Womble

Answer (score 0):

A protocol would work well here. You can define the properties the protocol requires, and then apply that to any class you want to use these in.

```
protocol Brandable {
    var kBrandColor: UIColor { get }
    var kMeaning: Int { get }
}

class Foo: Brandable {
    let kBrandColor: UIColor = .red
    let kMeaning: Int = 42
}
```

If you want to reuse the printStuff function, you can also put that in the protocol, and put a base implementation in an extension:

```
protocol Brandable {
    var kBrandColor: UIColor { get }
    var kMeaning: Int { get }

    func printStuff()
}

extension Brandable {
    func printStuff() {
        print("Brand Color is: \(kBrandColor)")
        print("The meaning of life is: \(kMeaning)")
    }
}

class Foo: Brandable {
    let kBrandColor: UIColor = .red
    let kMeaning: Int = 42
}

class Bar: Brandable {
    let kBrandColor: UIColor = .blue
    let kMeaning: Int = 100
}

Foo().printStuff()
Bar().printStuff()
```

The same can be done with the makeStuff() function. Shared functionality goes in the protocol and its extension. If you need to change the behavior in some class, you only need to add your own printStuff or makeStuff function to override the protocol's default implementation.

Comment: Thank you Nima. That is an interesting idea. It doesn't solve my problem of overall cleanliness and readability, but it does give me some ideas as to how to better structure some of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol like `Identifiable` with an `identifier` property. Then make any class that you want identifiable conform to it. It's the protocol oriented approach.

```
protocol Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { get }
}
extension Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

class X: Identifiable {}
```

You also don't need to refer to the class name. Just call `type(of: instance).identifier`.